# PDF thumbnails and preview in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, pdf

I've got a Microsoft Access database, and some PDF files. Right now, my Access database just shows a link to the PDF file with a .pdf generic icon.

What I want is a thumbnail view (like you get in Windows Explorer) of the PDF.

Second, right now when I click the PDF link, it is opening the PDF externally in Adobe Reader. How can I get it to open in preview mode within Access?

Comment: What requirement is hindered by using Adobe Reader instead of an internal view of the .pdf file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these will need the use of an embedded activeX control in your access app. There are many of them, some free, some not, depending on what you are planning to do. For a 'view only' use, I think you should be able to find something free. We have been using the [foxit reader](http://cdn04.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/enu/FoxitActiveX30_guide.pdf) and the more complex [amyuni](http://www.amyuni.com) controls in our apps with some success.

The principle are the following:

- You have to add the corresponding activeX file in the available references of your app (VBA screen, tools, select)
- You can then insert the corresponding control on a form, altogether with some 'empty' menus or controls
- You can use these menus or controls to initiate the different methods available for the PDF control (choose a file, next/previous page, zoom in/out, etc.)
- Depending on the vendor, some of these methods can be directly embedded in the activeX control
- I am sure you can google and find some examples of such work with VBA or even VB

If you distribute your access app, you will then have to distribute the activeX file with it. In most of the cases (if not all), distribution of the activeX file is free.

Answer (score 1):

As a normal rule, I don't like embedding things that use external software inside of a form.

However, Access 2010 does have a new web control. You place that control in a form and set the URL to the path name of the pdf (or picture etc.) then it will render and display that pdf inside of the form. This works quite well as long as some pdf viewer is installed.

I do caution these approaches since updates to PDF viewer or even users having a different pdf viewer can often cause problems and cost you support dollars. As noted, I think using the new web browser control is risky, but at least far less risk than most methods. Since the new browser control is native to Access 2010, then you can quite much attempt this idea in production code, but I would still try to stick with a simple click to view that launches whatever pdf software the user happens to be running on that computer.